# $.getJSON data not displaying in loop with ajaxSubmit

Tags: php, jquery

I've been having a few issues trying to execute a dynamically loaded form with jquery. Here is my code:

```
$(this).ajaxSubmit({ 
    url: '/postform1.php',
    type: 'post',
    //target: '#preview',
    success: function(msg) {

        var s = msg + '<form name="sr" id="sr" action="postform.php" method="post"><input type="text" /></form>';
        $('#preview').html(s);

        $.getJSON("/postform1.php", function(data){
        var counter = 0;
        if(data) {
           $.each(data, function(i, val) {
                var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", val);
                newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<label>' + i + ' : </label>' + '<input type="text" name="' + i + '" id="' + i + '" value="' + val + '" >');
                newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#sr");
                counter++;
            });
        }
        });
    }
 });
```

I was initially echoing the whole form from postform1.php but found the form was not submitting. I dont know if this is the right way of going about it either but figured i'd give it a try. If anyone has any ideas it would be great ro hear from you.

Comment: Are you using a plugin? `ajaxSubmit()` isn't a standard jQuery function.

Answer (score 0):

You missed to declare:

```
contentType: " ... ",
dataType: " ... "
```

Comment: i added this earlier but then i dont get a successful response.

Comment: what did you put there in replacement of my `" ... "` ?

Comment: I put 'json', i was reading this article, http://www.mydeveloperblog.com/jquery/jquery-api/ajaxsubmit-object-form-jquery-api/, the bit where it talks about JSON data

Comment: add this: `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json"`

Comment: I was echoing something else in addition to the json data so i've removed this and i'm getting a successful response. Its just not looping through the array now.

Comment: i've removed the loop,  $.getJSON("/postform1.php", function(data){ }); so i have success: function(data) {  $.each(data, function(i, val) { ..., i only get the first item in the array though

Answer (score 0):

thanks for looking into this, managed to sort it. I just changed this also:

```
var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", val);  
            newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<label>' + i + ' : </label>' + '<input type="text" name="' + i + '" id="' + i + '" value="' + val + '" >');  
            newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#sr");  
            counter++;
```

to this:

```
var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", val);
                newTextBoxDiv.html('<label>' + i + ' : </label>' + '<input type="text" name="' + i + '" id="' + i + '" value="' + val + '" >');
                newTextBoxDiv.appendTo(".sr");
                counter++;
```